# Drawing a boundary in on a scatterplot to identify outliers using a Copula

Tags: r

I have a scatterplot around which I want to draw an elliptical boundary to identify outliers:

```
library(MASS)
mu <- c(7, 5); 
sigma <- matrix(c(1, 1/2, 1/2, 1), 2); 
nu <- 4
n <- 4e3 
y <- t(t(mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(mu)), sigma) / sqrt(nu / rchisq(n, nu))) + mu)
plot(y[,1],y[,2])
```

I can draw quantile lines:

```
 abline(v=quantile(y[,1],c(0.05,0.95)))
 abline(h=quantile(y[,2],c(0.05,0.95)))
```

But how can I improve on this using Copulas?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `confidence.ellipse()` function in the `car` package might be useful.